# Hide/Delete all music that I did not upload to Google Play?

Tags: google-play-music

Using/playing with Google Play Music to index and (I guess) upload my music collection so I can access it from anywhere, even at work.

The problem is that Google has added a large number of music albums, songs, and artists that I did not upload (because I absolutely would *never* listen to some of this kind of music). I assume Google has a deal with some artists to push their music for free. I don't care for any of it.

Aside from randomly happening across them and deleting each album as I find them and subsequently get more annoyed, is there a way to either play only my music, filter out these songs Google added, delete all tracks I did not personally upload, or just get rid of this music I didn't upload??? My preference is to flat out delete them, if possible.

Comment: Which screen is Google Play adding these songs/albums? Your [all songs page](https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=0#/all)?